# Images are not loading

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I have some code to change *user image*. But after changing it I have to press `control+shift+R` to see changes.

I changed `File::delete()` to `unlink()`. But it did not work.

Controller code:

```
public function index(){
    $id = Auth::id();
    $info = Admin::select('name', 'login', 'image')- 
    >where('id', $id)->first();

    return view('admin.index')->with('info', $info);
}

public function changes(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name'         => 'required',
        'login'        => 'required',
    ]);
    $login = Auth::user()->login;
    $admin =  Admin::where('login', $login)->first();


    if($admin){

        $admin->name = $request['name'];
        $admin->login = $request['login'];
        if(!is_null($request['old_password']) and !is_null($request['new_password'])){
            $this->validate($request,[
                'new_password'         => 'required',
                'old_password'        => 'required',
            ]);
            if(Hash::check($request['old_password'], Auth::user()->password)){
                $new_password = Hash::make($request['new_password']);
                $admin->password = $new_password;
            }
        }
        if(!is_null($request['profile_image'])){
            $this->validate($request,[
                'profile_image'         => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',
            ]);

            if (!is_null(Auth::user()->image)) {

                $admin_image = public_path() .'/'. Auth::user()->image;
                if((File::exists($admin_image))){
                    File::delete($admin_image);
                }
            }
            $image = $request->file('profile_image');
            $image_extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image_name= Auth::id() .'.'. $image_extension;
            $image->move(public_path('admin_assets/assets/images/users'), $image_name);
            $admin->image = $image_name;

        }
        $admin->save();
    }
    return redirect()->route('admin.index');
}
```

I think I should refresh public folder in index action, but how?

Comment: If the new image has the same URL (same name and path) of the old image the browser uses the old image that has in his own cache. You should change name or append a versioned querystring (something like ?v=2) to the image URL to force the browser to request the new image.

Comment: Is there else version to do it/

Comment: Yes there is another: Ctrl+F5

Comment: :) I added the version to images, and it worked

Comment: Glad to be of help, I added a full answer for clearness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the *new image* has the same `URL` (same name and path in your case) of the *old image* the browser uses the old image that has in his own cache.

The best solutions for this issue, apart asking the user to press `Ctrl+F5` (or `Ctrl+Shift+R`) to clear the *page cache*, are:

1. Change **name** to the image each time the user changes the image itself.
2. Append a **versioned querystring** (something like `?v=2`) to the image `URL` to force the browser to request the new image: the `URL` is different from everything it has in cache so it's forced to get the new resource.